# ffmpeg At least one output file must be specified using Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-compression

I'm executing a python script for FFmpeg encoding. When executing the script I got an error Saying that :

> At least one output file must be specified

Even if I did specifies it:

```
command = [FFMPEG_BIN,'-i',file, '-s',WIDTH_X_HEIGHT,'-r', FRAME_RATE,'-c:v libx265', outputName ]

subprocess.call(command)  # encode the video
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your problem is the `-c:v libx265` part. That's two arguments, but combining them like that in one string makes it one argument passed to the process. Split that string on the space in your list. Currently, it thinks `outputName` is an argument to the (non-existant) `-c:v libx265` switch.

Comment: Thanks@Oskar it worked.

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your thing!